# Accessing Tomcat 8 running in Eclipse from another computer?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat8

I have been trying to solve this issue for hours without success.

I have 2 PCs:

- The first one is used a server, on which I installed Eclipse and Tomcat.
- The second one is used as a client.

When I run Tomcat in Eclipse on the server and try to access the web application from the client (using http://192.168.0.10/...) I get Web Page Not Available message on the browser.

**However if I use the same url on the server itself, it works.**

**If I launch Tomcat as standalone (not within eclipse) and I try to connect from the client it works !!!**

My guess is that eclipse is pushing some configuration in Tomcat to deny remote access, but so far I failed to figure out what are they.

Any idea ??

**UPDATE**:
After a day long work, I have come up with something but still not the best solution.
On the server side, I have launched Tomcat in Remote Debugging mode and Eclipse connects to it remotely (even though both are on the same computer).
But still this is not ideal because each time I modify the code I have to export it as war and reload it in Tomcat.

PS. In case you are curious to know why not running everything on the same computer? that's because I am working on a client/server project and both take big resources that can't fit on only one modest machine.

In case you have an idea of a better solution, thanks for sharing.

Regards

Comment: Explaining _how_ you are launching this from eclipse might yield some insight. Are you using some eclipse menu or plugin, or simply running the usual tomcat main class?

Comment: I downloaded Tomcat, then used the Preferences > Server menu to tell Eclipse to where to find the Tomcat installation (ex: C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.21)

Comment: Most likely, Eclipse tells tomcat to bind to only 127.0.0.1. Perhaps there is an eclipse config someplace to tell it to bind to * instead.

Comment: That's what I was trying to figure out for hours without success :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found it !

After two days of research and hundreds of posts scanned! I discovered what was the problem:

When launching Tomcat as standalone the process that is used is **java.exe**, while when launching it from Eclipse (whether Debug or Run) the process used is **javaw.exe**

When I checked my firewall settings, the **javaw.exe** was blocked and thus external requests are blocked even though the port 8080 was allowed in the firewall.

I hope this will help anyone who gets the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check your firewall settings.

Comment: That's what I did int the first place. I opened the port 8080. But what I was unaware of is that the process **javaw.exe**, launched by Eclipse, is blocked. Unfortunately it took quite a while to discover this. I spent most of the time tinkering with xml configuration for a solution.
Thx anyway...